# Page title "Recently Returned Migration" should be pluralized

Tags: bug, migration, 10k-tools, plurals

The 10k tools have a page with [recently returned migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/posts/migrated/returned) (screenshot below for those with less than 10k). Even though it usually does not show just 1 migration, its title is "Recently Returned Migration", so it's missing an 's'.

[image]